# Facing "No disk Error" when pinging in command prompt

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I don't know if this is the right place to ask question like this, But I am facing an "No Disk Error" whenever I do 'ping' in the command prompt as below;

[image]

Just for the info, there is no drive E on my computer. Its really annoying. Can someone help?

Comment: Is there a ping.bat in the directory where you issue the ping command?
Or perhaps a ping.bat in your path? Someone might be playing a joke on you.

Answer (score 0):

I really thanks to all who tried to figure out the solution. I am thankful for their time.

I just got workaround from a site. and I done the following changes..And now I am running the command prompt as Administrator.

Here what I done:

```
right click on cmd > shortcut tab > advanced > check the box "run as admin" > OK > Apply
```

**Edit:**

Well I just got it that why this Error occurs. I have checked my `Path` from `Environment Variables` that one of the path entry is directing to the `E Drive`, So I just removed it and now everything if working fine.

And I just revert the option of "running the command prompt as Administrator" to the normal one.

Thanks for the help and advise.

Comment: That doesn't some like a very good fix. What website did you get it from, and were there any parameters after your 'ping' command?